# Why i can't receive delivery or read receipt?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using the phpmailer class to develop the feature.

Here is the simple script to send out email and request for read receipt.

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "cshailesh157@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "******************";
    $mail->ConfirmReadingTo = "cshailesh157@gmail.com";
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Return-Receipt-To',"Shailesh Chauhan <cshailesh157@gmail.com>");
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Read-Receipt-To',"Shailesh Chauhan <cshailesh157@gmail.com>");
    $mail->addCustomHeader('X-Confirm-Reading-To',"Shailesh Chauhan <cshailesh157@gmail.com>");
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Generate-Delivery-Report',"Shailesh Chauhan <cshailesh157@gmail.com>");
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Disposition-Notification-To',"Shailesh Chauhan <cshailesh157@gmail.com>");
    $mail->setFrom('cshailesh157@gmail.com', 'Shailesh Chauhan');
    $mail->addReplyTo('cshailesh157@gmail.com');
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->addAddress('test.presntr@gmail.com');
    $mail->Subject = 'Testing For SMTP';
    $mail->Body = 'Testing For SMTP Body';
    if($mail->send()){
        echo 'send';
    }else{
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Mail was successfully sent.But i can not receive any read receipt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether read receipts are sent is entirely up to the receiving email client. Most do not support them any more because of widespread abuse by spammers. So you can request them, exactly as you are, but it's very unlikely you will actually get any.

Comment: I was try to get read receipt from gmail but read receipt not supported by gmail that's was work on another mail server.